# PHP A good algorithm to loop through an array to search for strings?

Tags: php

I am looking for help to write an efficient PHP algorithm to help me find occurances of a String within another string. Here is currently the situation.

I have two arrays. The first array is the array with text that needs searched (haystack). The second array is an array of terms ot find (needle).

I know that my first array has at least one of my terms from the needles. So, the algorithm needs to say 'is array2[0] found inside array1[0]? if not, loop, is array2[1] found inside array1[0], etc'  If it is found, exit, advance array1[1] pointer and repeat the process.

I want to make sure this is efficient as I have 10s of 1000s of entries to pricess, and my needle array has 1100 individual needles.

Comment: You're probably looking for the [Boyer-Moore algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boyer%E2%80%93Moore_string_search_algorithm) or one of its variants – they have approximately **O(N)** complexity. The original lets you cache a preprocessing step which could save you some time if you reuse the same needles a lot.

Comment: (http://johannburkard.de/software/stringsearch/ has a bunch of decent implementations of the algorithms you could try and port into PHP, or search for an existing one.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, let's start with this algorithm, it might not be the fastest but the result is what you want. (Keep loping UNTIL you found the first match)

```
<?php
for ($i = 0; $i < 1000; $i++) {
    $haystack[] = "Lorem ipsum dolor";
    $needle[] = "no match";
}
// $haystack = array("Lorem ipsum dolor", "Quisque placerat", "Cras quis porttitor orci");
//$needle = array("quis", "Lorem");
$timestamp1 = time() +  microtime();
foreach ($haystack as $word){
    foreach ($needle as $pattern){
        if(strpos($word, $pattern) === false){
            //Keep looping
        }else{
            //exit inner loop
            print "'".$pattern."' is in '".$word."'<br />";
            break;
        }
    }
}

$timestamp2 = time() + microtime();
print "It took me ".($timestamp2 - $timestamp1)." seconds to realize there was no match";
```

?>

//EDIT: I commented the hard coded array, creating it now dynamically an added a timer.
It takes about 1 second max, if there is no match.

Comment: Johannes, thanks for that. Your script uses strpos while mine was using stristri. Switching functions made my script perform a LOT better.

Answer (score 1):

A trie data structure of the haystack recorded with some other informations like word position (page, line and word number) is more efficient. It uses a divide and conquer strategy to avoid useless lookups. With a loop strategy every item in the haystack would be searched. A trie sort the haystack and you can skip some haystacks. Here is an example in PHP: http://phpir.com/tries-and-wildcards